# R prob = TRUE in hist doesn't give out a density distribution

Tags: r, histogram

```
earthquake <- function(lambda=1, n_sim =10, n=100){
  meanls <- c()
  for (i in 1:n){
    meanls <- c(meanls,round(mean(rexp(n_sim,1/lambda)),2))
  }
  return(meanls)
}
xbar <- earthquake(2.4,1000,40)
hist(xbar, prob=TRUE, col="moccasin",las= TRUE)
```

I have the code above, and it should return a density distribution histogram since I set probability to TRUE, while I just get frequency diagram. Is there anything else I should do with the data?

Comment: You are getting the density distribution - switch to `prob = FALSE` and you will see the difference in labels. Densities are scaled based on the x-axis units so that the total area adds up to 1. Your x-axis covers a narrow range, so that's why you see many density values > 1.

Comment: thank you, I saw the difference, but is there a way to change that back to scale from 0 - 1? Because I will also put a theoretical density curve there and they seems not to be in the same pace.

Comment: Density functions aren't on the scale of 0 to 1. It's not clear what you are asking for. Densities have the property that the area under the curve sums to 1. Buy this doesn't mean all y values are less than 1. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to add 1. theoretical 2. emprical curve on the histogram. ```#actual pdf:
x <- seq(2,3, length =100)
curve(dnorm(x, mean =2.4, sd=2.4/sqrt(40)), col="blue", add=TRUE, lwd=2)
#emprical pdf:
lines(density(xbar),col="red", lwd = 2)``` while these two lines are in different scale so in order to be able to compare them I will need them to be in the same scale...Does it make sense for the question?

Comment: What are you using for the standard deviation in the normal curve?

Answer (score 1):

If you set a random seed you can replicate your results. Otherwise you will need to adjust your `xlim=` according to your data. You do not say why you are using `sd=2.4/sqrt(40))` as the standard deviation instead of `sd(xbar)` which is what I have used here. That produces a very broad, flat curve that does not match the data at all. If you wanted the standard error curve, that would be `sd(xbar)/sqrt(40)`.

```
set.seed(42)
xbar <- earthquake(2.4, 1000, 40)
range(xbar)
# [1] 2.19 2.59
hist(xbar, prob=TRUE, xlim=c(2.1, 2.7), col="moccasin", las= TRUE)
x <- seq(2.1, 2.7, length.out=100)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(xbar), sd=sd(xbar)), col="blue", add=TRUE, lwd=2)
lines(density(xbar), col="red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]